# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object for list in list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list in a column of a data frame:

```
emaildf['email'][0] = ["abc@gmail.com","abc@yahoo.com","abc@abc.com"]
```

I want to iterate over each row (lets assume i) and match if the an object (assume j) in i  contains a substring: for example:

```
for i in emaildf['email']:
    for j in i:
         do_something:
```

Here is my code:

```
Private_Email = []
for index,row in emaildf.iterrows():
    for i in row['email']:
        if len(re.findall("gmail|hotmail|yahoo|msn", row['email'])) > 0:
            Private_Email.append(row['email'])
        else:
            Private_Email.append('No Gmail/Hotmail/MSN/Yahoo domains found.')
emaildf['Private_Email'] = Private_Email
```

This is the error i'm getting:

> ----> 4         if len(re.findall("gmail|hotmail|yahoo|msn", row['email'])) > 0: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Note:
Input:

```
re.findall("gmail|hotmail|yahoo|msn", "abc@gmail.com")
```

Output:

```
['gmail']
```

So that's why I'm checking for the length of the list.

Comment: You probably mean `for j in i` not `for j in in emaildf['email'][i]` since `i` is the data, not the list index.

Comment: Yes, thank you, changed it.

Comment: Which line in your code now gives you the `TypeError` ?

Comment: Line 4 - I've edited the question

Comment: No idea why close this question as "Needs debugging details", they are at the top of the question. Note you should avoid using `re.findall` on dataframes as you do not leverage the vectorized Pandas functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting TypeError:

```
----> 4         if len(re.findall("gmail|hotmail|yahoo|msn", row['email'])) > 0:
```

here because `row['email']` is a list, not a string, so you can't apply `re.findall` which expected a string, not a list.

Now, it seems your particular problem can be solved without even iterating over dataframe rows. Try:

```
emails = emaildf['email'].explode()
emails = pd.Series(np.where(emails.str.contains("gmail|hotmail|yahoo|msn").replace(np.nan, False), emails, np.nan), index=emails.index)
emails = emails.groupby(emails.index).apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if pd.notna(y)]).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)>1 else (x[0] if len(x)==1 else np.nan))
df['Private_Email'] = np.where(pd.notna(emails), emails, 'No Gmail/Hotmail/MSN/Yahoo domains found.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a regex when you simply want to make sure a substring is present within a string.

You can keep your search keywords in a list, and use `.apply` to go through each value in the list inside the `email` column, and filter out any value that does not contain any keyword from the keyword list.

See this Python code:

```py
import pandas as pd
emaildf = pd.DataFrame({'email':[["abc@gmail.com","abc@yahoo.com","abc@abc.com"]]})
keywords = ["gmail", "hotmail", "yahoo", "msn"]
emaildf['Private_Email'] = emaildf['email'].apply(lambda row: [x for x in row if any(key in x for key in keywords)])
# => >>> emaildf['Private_Email']
#    0    [abc@gmail.com, abc@yahoo.com]
#    Name: Private_Email, dtype: object
```

The `.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row if any(key in x for key in keywords)])` part iterates over each string (`x`) in the `row` value and keeps any `x` string if any `key` is present in it.